# Reuse Chart in Multiple Powerpoint Slides

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I want to create a flow chart once in Powerpoint, then reuse and/or crop it in multiple slides. Then, I want any changes I make to be propagated across all slides so I don't have to copy/paste many times.

The reason I want to do this is to create context with different components of the flow chart, but be able to modify the chart in one place and have it apply on the other slides.

Is this possible to do?

note: I'm in Powerpoint for Mac 2011.

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a slide master, insert the image on the master, then apply the master to relative slides. When you edit the slide master all associated slides will update.